# How to show only 20 records instead of the default 80 in a Odoo 10 tree view?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

When you open a tree view, it always shows 80 records per page. I would like to see 20 records instead of 80 in `sale` module. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the action which opens the tree view where you want to see only 20 records, you only have to set its `limit` field to 20.

For example, if you want to see only 20 records per page in the customers tree view (the XML ID of the action which opens this view is `base.action_partner_form`):

```
<record id="base.action_partner_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="limit" eval="20"/>
</record>
```